# How to open exernal link in new window through PHP?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open All external link into new window/tab through php without touching every external link code. and i don't want to this without target="blank".

I can do this through javascript but i want to know if there is a PHP solution.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to do this with target="_blank" ?

Comment: And do you also mean you want to know if there is a non-Javascript solution?

Comment: PHP is not the issue here. PHP outputs HTML and once it is on the client's screen it is a HTML issue.

Comment: "I dont want to do this without..."  and  "I can do this through X but want to know if there is an X solution"  are really idiotic sentences.  Back to grammar school, dude.

Comment: Beside the technical issue, there are usability issues: I hate when a server decides for me that links should be opened in a new window (I can do that myself, thanks), I hate even more links needing JS to open when not needed, and users can have JS disabled anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This job cannot be done with PHP. PHP is on the server side while your problem requires interaction with the client. This is a classical thing you'd use javascript for.

In case you use JQuery things become extremely simple:

```
// pretend you have links in your page <a href="link.htm" rel="external">Link</a>
// please note that the rel-value can be chosen at will
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[rel="external"]').click(function() {
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got this one right, but if you're looking for a JS alternative to "target=blank" then this one works and is xhtml valid:

onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;"

Comment: apikot thx for quick reply.  I know abou javascript method but wanted to know if there any PHP method and i don't want to edit every external link manually . If i have a 100 links on a page then i need a one script which can scan all external link and open into new window if clicked.

Comment: You'd do this via JS as well, here is a short snippet using mootools:

$$('a').each(function(el){
   if(el.rel == 'external')
   {
     el.addEvent('click', function(e) {
        e = new Event(e).stop;
        window.open(el.href, '_blank');
     });
   }
});

Comment: What's with all these web developers who don't understand the difference between server-side and client-side code? I'm seeing it all the time on SO, and it's dispiriting.

Answer (score 1):

[Base target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) should do it for you.